# Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported on Payum Laravel Package payment_done controller

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payum

I'm working with Payum Laravel Package 0.11.1, and facing the error **Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported** on payment done controller:

```
$status = new GetHumanStatus($token);
$payment->execute($status);
```

i.e.:
I'm redirected from PaypalController on

```
return $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
```

to **http://myapp.local:8000/app/payment_done?payum_token=_lLGI4Mxk-UKX4FNUiyq0j94IrY_iLjRoMZfWc8Bdg0**

I can see on my storage the files **payum-model-_lLGI4Mxk-UKX4FNUiyq0j94IrY_iLjRoMZfWc8Bdg0** and **payum-model-5417d0934a306**

The $token resultant from

```
$request = \App::make('request');
$request->attributes->set('payum_token', $payum_token);
$token = $this->getHttpRequestVerifier()->verify($request);
```

Gives me the result:

```
$token->getDetails() = Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject#5417d0934a306
$token->getHash() = _lLGI4Mxk-UKX4FNUiyq0j94IrY_iLjRoMZfWc8Bdg0
$token->getPaymentName() = paypal-pro
```

If I try to reach payment_done controller with an invalid payum_token, it gives the  error: **A token with hash `_lLGI4Mxk-UKX4FNUiyq0j94IrY_iLjRoMZfWc8Bdg1` could not be found.** and if I try it with a valid token the **Request GetHumanStatus{model: ArrayObject} is not supported**. As I can see on storage a token with equivalent $token details arrayobject ID, I guess my $payments is not properly constructed on config.php.

Comment: There was a bug in Payum, fixed -https://github.com/Payum/PayumLaravelPackage/issues/12#issuecomment-55740673

Comment: Thank you Maksim, once again. Now I've full working paypal payment flow. Regards